# How to create a stream that emulates the behaviour of a nested loop that is initialised to 1 + the index of the outer loop

Tags: java, collections, java-8, nested, java-stream

I have the following method that takes a `List<Point2D>` and creates a `Line2D` for each line between every one of the points.

```
public List<Line2D> getAllPointToPointLines() {
    List<Point2D> points = getAllPoints();
    List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); j++) {
            lines.add(new Line2D.Double(points.get(i), points.get(j)));
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

To avoid duplicate lines by creating `Line2D(pointA, pointB)` as well as `Line2D(pointB, pointA)`, the inner loop is initialised to one more than the current index of the outer loop.

The closest I have managed to get to this behaviour with a stream is the following method.

```
public List<Line2D> getAllPointToPointLines() {
    return points.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> points.stream().filter(j -> !i.equals(j))
                    .map(j -> new Line2D.Double(i, j))).collect(toList());
}
```

However this of course creates duplicate lines for the reason mentioned above.

I have tested @Eugene 's answer with the following code:

```
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        points.getAllPointToPointLines();
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Non-stream - " + stopwatch.getTimeString());

    stopwatch.reset();
    stopwatch.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        points.getAllPointToPointLinesStream();
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Stream - " + stopwatch.getTimeString());
```

And with the optimisation provided by @fge the output is roughly 150ms for the original approach and 650ms for the alternative stream approach.

Comment: Why would you refactor to streams if imperative approach is easier to understand? Your stream example seems to be less effective than one nested for-loop.

Comment: Mostly with the hope of making it more efficient as the collection of points is likely to be very large. I realise that a stream isn't automatically better but I'm looking for any way to make it more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need something like this (I haven't compiled it *exactly* with your use case though)

```
 int size = points.size();
 IntStream.range(0, size)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, size)
                                   .mapToObj(j -> new Line2D.Double(points.get(i), points.get(j))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I know this is not really an optimization but if we suppose that the points list doesn't change, you can make its .size() a variable and use it :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. However, testing each method with 100,000 runs each, the non-stream version takes 181ms to complete and this solution takes 718ms so it appears the traditional approach might be best.

Comment: @fge it is an optimization indeed. thank you for the comment.

Comment: @ChrisTopher well yes, but that of course *depends* on how you test - meaning that the usual approach will be faster indeed, but I would not expect a `4x` as you report.

Comment: @Eugene would it be proper to add my test code as an edit to the original post? I can't show you it here as it's too many character, it's very possible that I am not performing a fair test

Comment: @ChrisTopher absolutely! please also include the relevant classes

Comment: @Eugene Please see the edit, and also I am fairly sure there wouldn't be any benefit to posting any more of my code, the method in question is performed quite independently from any other code

Comment: @ChrisTopher unfortunately I am out of time testing this... hopefully I will find soon. nevertheless form my previous testings - there are differences indeed and the plain for loops are faster, but by tens of milliseconds faster, not `4x`. I usually test this with `jmh`